# Entity Framework: mix table per type and table per hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

I have two tables in my database:

- BaseEntity
- Fund

The "Fund" entity inherits from "BaseEtity" with "table per type".

In my business model I have different types of "Fund":

- Head-Fund
- Direct-Investment-Fund
- etc.

I would like to have different entities for those types with "table per hierarchy", meaning that I still only have one "Fund" table with a type-discriminator column.

Is there a way to have "table per hierarchy" on an entity that derives from a base class with "table per type"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible, see this post for reference:

[Can I mix Table per Hierarchy and Table per Type in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605892/can-i-mix-table-per-hierarchy-and-table-per-type-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I saw this post earlier, but I wanted to keep my hopes up and ask again :) Maybe someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: That post presents a different, more complex scenario. It is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible - I have had this working in EF4 for some time now.

```
Define EntityA and map to TableA

Define EntityB: EntityA and map to TableB

Define EntityC: EntityA and map to TableC

Define EntityD: EntityC and map to TableC
    with condition on a column from table C

Define EntityE: EntityC and map to TableC
    with a different condition on a column from table C
```

Comment: Are you using code-first for that? I'm working with model-first and the EF designer.

Comment: @SolarX, If you were really using model first and not database first, EF would create SQL script that creates tables according to table per type mapping convention. I think you are actually using database first too (mapping to existing tables, not creating new tables from edmx), then reshaping the initial model to the way you want it to work.

Comment: Do you create tables from model, or map model to existing tables, or a bit of both? Which ever way you do it, this mapping is possible.

Comment: As I said I use model first. Ergo I create tables from the model (and this way only).

Comment: Ok, however EF only uses TPT for model-first, unless you edited the .tt file that creates the SQL script. - Therefore your question makes no sense in this context.

Comment: The question does not state you are generating the tables from entities (pure model-first). The selected answer is irrelvent to you (also deals with db-first) and in general this mapping IS possible, no matter which way you work, in model-first you just have to modify the T4 that creates the tables (you can have it read the documentation fields that the designer has for the entities to decide what kind of inheritance tables to generate. Leaving an incorrect accepted answer will just cause more misconception about EF.