# How can I mix TPH and TPT in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

### Initial situation

I have an application that uses an existing database, currently using **NHibernate** as O/R-Mapper.
Now I need to migrate to **Entity Framework 6.1.1** using **Code First** and **Fluent API Configuration**.

But now I have a problem with a part of the data model because it uses different types of inheritance strategies (TPT and TPH)

### Structure

*Note: Posting the complete data model here seemed a bit too enormous to me so I reproduced the problem I face in a small POC program.*

```
CLASS                  | TABLE              | TYPE
-----------------------+--------------------+------
BaseEntity (abstract)  | BaseTable          |
Inherited_TPH          | BaseTable          |  1
Inherited_TPT          | Inherited_TPT      |  2
```

The column used as discrimator in the table is called `Type`

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034803/314334) I added an abstract class `Intermediate_TPH` as intermediate layer:

[image: Diagram of classes and mapping]

Some sample data: Entry with `ID=3` is of type `Inherited_TPT`

[image: Data]

### Code

These are my entity classes and my context class:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext ( string connectionString )
        : base ( connectionString )
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Inherited_TPH> TPH_Set { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inherited_TPT> TPT_Set { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomethingElse> Another_Set { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entity<BaseEntity> ()
        .ToTable ( "BaseTable" );

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Inherited_TPH> ()
        .Map ( t => t.Requires ( "Type" ).HasValue ( 1 ) );

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Intermediate_TPT> ()
        .Map ( t => t.Requires ( "Type" ).HasValue ( 2 ) );

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Intermediate_TPT> ()
        .Map<Inherited_TPT> ( t => t.ToTable ( "Inherited_TPT" ) ); 

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<SomethingElse> ()
        .ToTable ( "SomethingElse" )
        .HasKey ( t => t.Id );
    }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
public class Inherited_TPH : BaseEntity
{
}
public abstract class Intermediate_TPT : BaseEntity
{
}
public class Inherited_TPT : Intermediate_TPT
{
    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
}
public class SomethingElse
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Running the following code will give me an error.

```
    static void Main ( string[] args )
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext> ( null );
        var ctx = new MyContext ( @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=nh_ef;Integrated Security=true" );
        try
        {
            // Accessing Inherited_TPH works just fine
            foreach ( var item in ctx.TPH_Set ) Console.WriteLine ( "{0}: {1}", item.Id, item.Title );
            // Accessing Inherited_TPT works just fine
            foreach ( var item in ctx.TPT_Set ) Console.WriteLine ( "{0}: {1} ({2})", item.Id, item.Title, item.Comment );
            // The rror occurs when accessing ANOTHER entity:
            foreach ( var item in ctx.Another_Set ) Console.WriteLine ( "{0}: {1}", item.Id, item.Description );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( ex.Message );
            if( ex.InnerException != null ) { Console.WriteLine ( ex.InnerException.Message ); }
        }
    }
```

### Output

The program produces the following output:

> 1: Simpson
>   2: Johnson
>   3: Smith (More details about SMITH)
>   4: Miller (More details about MILLER)
>   An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> (26,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 14, 26:EntityTypes PoC.Inherited_TPH, PoC.Inherited_TPT are being mapped to the same rows in table BaseEntity. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

### Question

As you can see, the mapping **seems to work** because I can load all data from `Inherited_TPT` and `Inherited_TPH`. But when accessing another entity, **I get an exception**.

How do I need to configure the mapping to get rid of this error and be able to access the existing database structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. I'll post it here in case someone else will need the same behavior...

- The intermediate layer is not needed in this case
- The discriminator is only needed for TPH

So all we need to do is to change the definition of the mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    // Not changed
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<BaseEntity> ()
        .ToTable ( "BaseTable" );


    // --- CHANGED ---
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity> ()
        // TPH => Discriminator
        .Map<Inherited_TPH> ( m => m.Requires ( "Type" ).HasValue ( 1 ).IsOptional () ) 
        // TPT => Mapping to table
        .Map<Inherited_TPT> ( m => m.ToTable ( "Inherited_TPT" ) ); 

    // Not changed
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<SomethingElse> ()
        .ToTable ( "SomethingElse" )
        .HasKey ( t => t.Id );
}
```

Comment: How does "Inherited_TPT" know that it has to insert 2 in the type column?
If i implement the solution as described above i get the exception that type is a required column and i'm trying to insert a null value. Thanks in advance for any feedback you can give me :)

Comment: Some time has passed since I had to deal with this, so I might remember this wrong - but I think that the `Type` column should be nullable because of `.IsOptional()` and `Inherited_TPT`does not need to insert a value in `Type` because it is mapped to another Table (Join on Id)